# Is it possible to make Account Page Specific to any Application

Tags: apex, account, record-type, visualforce

Here is my scenario I have Account Object and I have entirely two different Application. Now i want to make Page Layout specific to the application which I select for the same profile users. I can some how achieve this using Record Types but I don't want to use record types because it will give option to select.

My whole point is that Page Layout for Account Object should be changed based on the Application which I select .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea.  In my experience, Users aren't savvy enough to realise when they're in a certain application and/or what that actually implies.  By having a different view for the same record based on what application they're in, will most probably create confusion.

Ideally, a particular Account record should always look the same.  This is part of the rule of least surprise.  If the application has a different context, the Account record should still look the same, however what you can do is display the information in a way that similar data is sectioned.  Users can then choose to minimise each section of data based on the reason they're looking at the record.

sfdcck's solution will do as you want, however it means you'll need to create VF pages and tabs for all instances of this, which will become a maintenance issue going forward.  It will cost significantly more in both time and money whenever an update is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own VisualForce Page with the layout you want and then create the Visual Force Tab of that Page. Make sure you assign this Tab in your app and remove the standard ones or other. 
This might solve your problem